# scala objects as fields

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [val and object inside a scala class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class)

Is there a substantive difference between:

```
class Foo {
  object timestamp extends java.util.Date
}
```

and

```
class Foo {
  val timestamp = new java.util.Date {}
}
```

What does it really mean to have a class with an object field?  What are they used for? Are there situations where you must use an object?

Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an `object` may be preferable if you need to add behavior to the field.  For example:

```
class Foo {
   object startDate extends java.util.Date {
      def isBusinessDay: Boolean = // ...
   }
}

class Bar {
   lazy val startDate = new java.util.Date {
      def isBusinessDay: Boolean = // ...
   }
}
```

The type of `foo.startDate` is `foo.startDate.type`, and a call to the `foo.startDate.isBusinessDay` method will be resolved statically.

The type of `bar.startDate`, on the other hand, is the structural type `java.util.Date{ def isBusinessDay: Boolean }`.  A call to `bar.startDate.isBusinessDay` will therefore use reflection and incur unnecessary runtime overhead.

Comment: Shame on me for asking more than one question; there are two correct answers now, but I'm only allowed to pick one. :(

Answer (score 5):

Two differences, one important, one subtle.  First, objects are lazily initiated.  For your purposes, this means your second example should be

```
class Foo {
  lazy val timestamp = new java.util.Date {}
}
```

for them to behave equivalently.  More subtly, each object has it's own unique type.  In the case of your example, `timestamp` will have type `Foo.timestamp.type`.  This normally isn't important in practice, but may cause surprises if you are accessing objects reflectively.

Comment: Picking nits a bit, isn't it the case that in either instance, timestamp has a unique type, but in the object case, the type is predictable, and in the val case it's some anon type?

Comment: Ok, looking at your other answer, it seems the reason we see object fields is from code that predates lazy val. I'd say lazy val is almost always preferred.

Comment: @Eric Actually, the type is also predictable in the `val` case, but it's a structural type. More in my answer...

Comment: Yes, object fields are most common in pre-2.6 Scala code, which was when lazy val was added.  There aren't many other usecases where they still make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Those do behave basically the same way.  I had assumed that `class X { object Y ... }` would simply provide a namespace for `X.Y`.  I used `Y` to store (constant) utility data related to `X` specifically because I expected one unique `X.Y`.  In fact, one new object was constructed for every new `X` which I discovered when doing memory profiling.