# val or object for immutable, final singleton object

Tags: scala, object, singleton, language-features, library-design

Which solution should be generally preferred, considering that the change is source compatible?

This

```
object Foo {
  val Bar = new Baz(42, "The answer", true)
}
```

or this?

```
object Foo {
  object Bar extends Baz(42, "The answer", true)
}
```

Comment: I would say first one is better if you want to modularize your API differently in the future without too much modification... but since the change is source compatible you can keep the second until needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [val and object inside a scala class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functional difference between the two constructs is that `object Bar` is only created when it is needed, while `val Bar` is created as soon as `object Foo` is used.  As a practical matter, this means you should use the object (or `lazy val`) if the right-hand side is expensive and won't always be needed.  Otherwise, `val` is probably simpler.

Also, note that if the class `Baz` is final, you won't be able to use the `object` style since you can't extend `Baz` (though you can still use `lazy val` if you want to defer creation until it's needed).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I meant with `final` that the variable `Bar` won't be reassigned. Isn't the bytecode for `object` slightly simpler than the code for `lazy val`?

Comment: @soc - Yes, `lazy val` is more complex code (and threadsafe).  And I edited my answer to make it clearer what I meant regarding `final`.

Comment: @soc - Doesn't look like it to me; the object initializer code doesn't seem to be thread-aware.  You can check the bytecode.

Comment: Afaik it uses the same strategy like singleton enums in Java where the VM guarantees thread-safety, not the bytecode.

Comment: @soc - Could be.  This isn't something I'm terribly familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

I say the first since in the second, you are creating a new class but don't add any information (no overriding of methods, values or new ones).