# Scala - new vs object extends

Tags: scala

What is the difference between defining an object using the new operator vs defining a standalone object by extending the class?

More specifically, given the type  `class GenericType { ... }`, what is the difference between `val a = new GenericType`  and `object a extends GenericType`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [val and object inside a scala class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a practical matter, `object` declarations are initialized with the same mechanism as `new` in the bytecode. However, there are quite a few differences:

- `object` as singletons -- each belongs to a class of which only one instance exists;
- `object` is lazily initialized -- they'll only be created/initialized when first referred to;
- an `object` and a `class` (or `trait`) of the same name are *companions*;
- methods defined on `object` generate static forwarders on the companion `class`;
- members of the `object` can access private members of the companion `class`;
- when searching for implicits, companion objects of relevant* classes or traits are looked into.

These are just some of the differences that I can think of right of the bat. There are probably others.

* What are the "relevant" classes or traits is a longer story -- look up questions on Stack Overflow that explain it if you are interested. Look at the wiki for the `scala` tag if you have trouble finding them.

Answer (score 5):

object definition (whether it extends something or not) means singleton object creation.

```
scala> class GenericType
defined class GenericType

scala> val a = new GenericType
a: GenericType = GenericType@2d581156

scala> val a = new GenericType
a: GenericType = GenericType@71e7c512

scala> object genericObject extends GenericType
defined module genericObject

scala> val a = genericObject
a: genericObject.type = genericObject$@5549fe36

scala> val a = genericObject
a: genericObject.type = genericObject$@5549fe36
```

Answer (score 2):

While `object` declarations have a different semantic than a `new` expression, a local `object` declaration is for all intents and purpose the same thing as a `lazy val` of the same name. Consider:

```
class Foo( name: String ) {
  println(name+".new")
  def doSomething( arg: Int ) {
    println(name+".doSomething("+arg+")")
  }
}

def bar( x: => Foo ) {
  x.doSomething(1)
  x.doSomething(2)
}

def test1() {
  lazy val a = new Foo("a")
  bar( a )
}

def test2() {
  object b extends Foo("b")
  bar( b )
}
```

`test1` defines `a` as a lazy val initialized with a new instance of `Foo`, while `test2` defines `b` as an `object` extending `Foo`.
In essence, both lazily create a new instance of `Foo` and give it a name (`a`/`b`).

You can try it in the REPL and verify that they both behave the same:

```
scala> test1()
a.new
a.doSomething(1)
a.doSomething(2)

scala> test2()
b.new
b.doSomething(1)
b.doSomething(2)
```

So despite the semantic differences between `object` and a `lazy val` (in particular the special treatment of `object`'s by the language, as outlined by Daniel C. Sobral),
a `lazy val` can always be substituted with a corresponding `object` (not that it's a very good practice), and the same goes for a `lazy val`/`object` that is a member of a class/trait.
The main practical difference I can think of will be that the object has a more specific static type: `b` is of type `b.type` (which extends `Foo`) while `a` has exactly the type `Foo`.