# What is the difference in following implicit implementations in type class solutions?

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, typeclass, implicit

In the example below:

```
trait Writer[A] {
 def write(a: A): String
}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class Student(name: String, roll: Int)

object DefaultStringWriters {
//here is implicit object, when to use object here?

implicit object PersonNameWriter extends Writer[Person] {
  def write(person: Person) = person.name
 }

//here is implicit val, when to use val here?

implicit val studentNameWriter = new Writer[Student] {
  def write(student: Student) = student.name
 }
}

object WriterUtil {
 def stringify[A](data: A)(implicit writer: HtmlWriter[A]): String = {
  writer.write(data)
 }
}

#It works here with both.
WriterUtil.stringify(Person("john", "person@john.com"))
res0: String = john

WriterUtil.stringify(Person("student", "student@student.com"))
res1: String = student
```

When do we use implicit object or val in practical cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differences

1. `val` is created during object initialization, and in the specified order. `object` is created lazily.
2. `object` creates a new singleton type (e.g. `PersonNameWriter.type`) `val` creates either no type (as in this case), or a structural type.
3. `val` can be overridden. `object` cannot.
4. `val` can be assigned any expression, e.g. `Foo()` or `new Foo`. `object` must be a class definition, and is more limited in the ways it can reuse code, e.g. `extends Foo`.

If you don't care about any of these differences, then it doesn't matter which one you choose. In that case, I recommend `val` because it removes the need for any synchronization.

Comment: In such a case above during the design of type class instances, what is the recommended approach?

Comment: @ceecer1, I would probably use `val` as I don't want to create a new type, and it doesn't need synchronization. But that's pure preference.

Comment: Thanks for your input.