# object vs val for singletons?

Tags: scala, singleton, traits

Which of the following ways is better/preferred? How are they different?

```
trait MyService {
  def foo: String
}

class MyTest {
  // variant 1
 object fooService1 extends MyService {
   val foo = "foo1"
 }
 // variant 2
 val fooService2 = new MyService {
   val foo = "foo2"
 }
 // (...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No practical difference, except that if you extend `MyTest` you will be able to override the `val` but not the `object`, [EDIT] and the object is instantiated lazily.

Also, possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class).